# Flutter fl_chart: Adding formatted date as tilted labels on X axis

Tags: flutter, user-interface, charts, flutter-charts

I am using fl_chart package in my Flutter application to add a Bar chart that is supposed to display dates (format - dd/mm/yy) in a titled fashion in the X - axis as shown in the below image

[image: Current UI state]

The code which generates this UI is as follows

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:vendors/gen/colors.gen.dart';
import 'package:vendors/src/shared/widgets/dividers/custom_divider.dart';
import 'package:vendors/src/shared/widgets/input/input_date_field.dart';

class ClaimsChart extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClaimsChart({super.key});

  @override
  State<ClaimsChart> createState() => _ClaimsChartState();
}

class _ClaimsChartState extends State<ClaimsChart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1.75,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: BarChart(
                BarChartData(
                  barGroups: _chartGroups(),
                  borderData: FlBorderData(
                      border: const Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black26),
                          left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black26))),
                  gridData: const FlGridData(show: false),
                  titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                    bottomTitles: AxisTitles(sideTitles: _bottomTitles),
                    leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                        sideTitles: SideTitles(
                            showTitles: true,
                            interval: 5,
                            reservedSize: 20,
                            getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) => Text(
                                  value.toInt().toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                                      fontSize: 12),
                                ))),
                    topTitles: const AxisTitles(
                        sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
                    rightTitles: const AxisTitles(
                        sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<BarChartGroupData> _chartGroups() {
    return List.generate(
            10,
            (index) =>
                ChartData(date: DateTime.now(), value: Random().nextInt(20)))
        .map((point) =>
            BarChartGroupData(x: point.date.microsecondsSinceEpoch, barRods: [
              BarChartRodData(
                  toY: point.value.toDouble(),
                  color: ColorName.barChart,
                  width: 12,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0)),
            ]))
        .toList();
  }

  SideTitles get _bottomTitles => SideTitles(
        showTitles: true,
        getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {
          String formattedDate = DateFormat("dd/mm/yy")
              .format(DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(value.toInt()));
          return SideTitleWidget(
              axisSide: meta.axisSide,
              // You can adjust the space as needed
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: -45 * (pi / 180),
                // Rotate by 45 degrees (convert to radians)
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                  child: Text(
                    formattedDate,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                      fontSize: 12,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ));
        },
      );
}

class ChartData {
  final DateTime date;
  final int value;

  ChartData({required this.date, this.value = 9});
}
```

Note - The ClaimsChart widget is part of a SingleChildScrollView

The expected UI should be like this

[image]

I have tried to add Top padding to move the Text title widget down by 10 points, but it just made the Text disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of `Transform.rotate` if you only want to rotate the formatted date text. There is an angle property in `SideTitleWidget` that can help you out.
Code snippet for your reference :-

```
     SideTitleWidget(
        axisSide: meta.axisSide,
        angle: 125,
        child: Text(
          formattedDate,
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
            fontSize: 12,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Let me know if it helps.